# From a given latitude on Earth, how to calculate the number of days in a year when the moon is lit on the bottom?

Tags: the-moon, orbital-mechanics

From a given latitude on Earth, is it possible to calculate the number of days in a year when there is a [wet moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_moon) , that is when the moon is lit on the bottom?

If, for example, I want to do the calculation for the year 2023, how should I go about this? And can I predict those days as well?

Comment: This post describes how to calculate it: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39152/how-to-calculate-the-moons-illuminated-fraction-tilt

Comment: Meeus covered this topic in one of the "Morsels" books, though I believe he called it a "moon as a boat".  He did not show how to calculate it, but showed the results of where it could happen and how often.